# Catalog product and Stock index Error

Tags: magento2, database, catalog, reindex, stock

I am getting this strange error while reindex, and I cannot find any solution on google or on stackoverflow.

> Stock index exception: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already
> exists: 1050 Table './mydb/cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated'
> already exists, query was: RENAME TABLE cataloginventory_stock_status
> TO
> cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated,cataloginventory_stock_status_replica
> TO
> cataloginventory_stock_status,cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated
> TO cataloginventory_stock_status_replica

already checked in `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/` and there is no `cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated` table

I am getting the same error for `catalog_category_product_index_store1_outdated`
Any help please.

Comment: anybody have an idea about this ticket?

Comment: @m2dubai please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem if someone passes from here

using terminal

cd /var/lib/mysql/dbname/

ls

search for the table with no `tablename.frm` and move to a safe place or delete the `tablename.ibd`

example (here renaming the table)

```
mv customer_grid_flat.ibd customer_grid_flat.ibd.old
```

now reindex, the tables will be regenerated